# Where to put binaries for use by all users?

Tags: software-installation

I have an binary I would like to make available to all users.

When installing an application for a single user, I would previously put my application in `/usr/local/{app_name}` and update the `$PATH` variable in my `.bash_rc` or equivalent to include the binary path (e.g. `/usr/local/{app_name}/bin`).

I believe this is fine for a local user, but if I want to make the binary available to all users where to I store the application?

Should I place the application under `/etc/{app-name}` and create a symlink for the binary to `/usr/bin` to avoid needing an update to `$PATH`?

I understand that `/usr` is mounted per user so would that not work for every user?

Comment: Why not just put it in `/usr/local/bin`? On most systems, that is already in everyone's `PATH` and wouldn't require anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the binary is self-sufficient regardless of its location, I would probably go for `/usr/local/bin` which should already be on most users' paths.  If it needs supplementary files, they can be installed wherever you prefer, and you can put a symbolic link to the binary, or the binary itself if it knows how to find its supplemtary files, into `/usr/local/bin` (or `/usr/bin`, or `/bin` or whichever directory you prefer).

`/usr` is *not* typically mounted "per-user".

`/etc`, one of the places you contemplate, is generally not understood to be a place for *programs* but rather a place for *configuration files*.

You may want to refer to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's another option which I prefer.

- Install applications to `/opt/applicationname` (see the [filesystem hierarchy standard entry](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html) on `/opt`for further reading).

Then you can either:

- Add/create:

  ```bash
  /etc/profile.d/application.sh

  export PATH=$PATH:/opt/applicationname/bin
  ```

Or

- Create a symlink from `/opt/applicationname/bin/application` to `/usr/local/bin/application`.