# Ubuntu - Run executable with customized name from anywhere

Tags: path, alias, application

I have installed etcher and I can run it from its installation directory (*.../balena-etcher-electron-1.7.9-linux-x64/squashfs-root*) with the command ./balena-etcher-electron. Well wonderful !

But now I would like to achieve the followings:

1. Run this app with my own command like "*etcher*" instead of entering "*./balena-etcher-electron*" --> Is there something to do with alias ?
2. Use this command "etcher" like any app command in the $PATH (example gedit) from anywhere.

What do I have to customize in this executable script ?

Or maybe I should have done "apt-get install etcher" then everything is already handled ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Google: how to add directory to PATH. Google: /etc/profile.d Google: how to create a symlink. A related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/719212/260833

Comment: Installing a package maintained for your Linux distribution, if such a package is available, would make _much_ more sense than installing the application manually. Especially if you're unsure about the sort of things you mention in your question.

Answer (score 0):

*1. Run this app with my own command like `etcher` instead of entering `./balena-etcher-electron`*

Then simply rename `balena-etcher-electron` to `etcher`:

```bash
mv ./balena-etcher-electron ./etcher
```

*2. Use this command `etcher` like any app command in the `$PATH` (example `gedit`) from anywhere.*

If you want to use it as if it was in `$PATH` then it should be in `$PATH`.

For example

```bash
sudo cp ./balena-etcher-electron /usr/bin/etcher
```

(or wherever your `$PATH` is).

ETA:
also consider the comment by @Kusalananda, makes good points.

Comment: Regarding your first point: That would only work if that directory is in `$PATH` (note that they don't seem to want to type `./`). It would make slightly more sense to create an alias, or to move it to some other directory that is already in `$PATH`, like you do in your second point (but if this works or not depends on whether the application expects to be installed in a particular location or not).  Also locally installed software should probably go in the `/usr/local` hierarchy, or you may accidentally overwrite package-managed files under `/usr`.